# Angular material calendar enabled days and services

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I'm trying to use angular material's calendar with enabled / disabled days. I need to read enabled days using a REST webservice, so I implemented an angular service with an operation to do it. Problem is that calendar tries to use the function that calculates if day is enabled or not before the service returns data.

I tried using 'resolve' in the state (service would be called synchronously before the controller is rendered), but the value is not inyected. How should I do it?

I'm using Angular 1.5 with typescript.

Thanks in advance